# Mouse right button in WatiN

Tags: c#, watin

How to use Right Mouse button in WatiN?

I tried the following code but it didn't work..

```
Div div1 = pzDev.Div("AppExplorer");
Span sp1 = div1.Span(Find.ById(new Regex("cl_")));
NameValueCollection eventProperties = new NameValueCollection();
eventProperties.Add("button", "2"); 
sp1.FireEvent("onmouseover",eventProperties);
Thread.Sleep(1000); 
sp1.FireEvent("onmousedown",eventProperties); 
sp1.FireEvent("onmouseup",eventProperties);
```

Can anyone suggest the right approach?

Answer (score 0):

This should work only if you have javascript event "onmouseover" or "onmousedown",etc. associated to your specified elements.

It will not made a right button, just simulate the call to a javascript event, like a right mouse click would have done.